# What changes should i make in this code,in order to make this two way chat working

Tags: java, serversocket

I am trying to make a 2 way chat system ,where two people would could chat using networking.

I have created this server side,which would manage the communication

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ServerSocket server=new ServerSocket(2000);
        ServerSocket server2=new ServerSocket(2001);
        System.out.println("srver is ready to to recieve therequest ,");
        Socket socket=server.accept();
        Socket socket2=server2.accept();
        System.out.println("requst received,conetion completed");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("wating for the client message");
        int a,b;
        OutputStream o=socket.getOutputStream();
        OutputStream o2=socket2.getOutputStream();
        InputStream i1=socket.getInputStream();
        InputStream i2=socket2.getInputStream();
        while(true)
        {
         while((a=i1.read())!=-1)
         {
             System.out.println(a);
             o2.write(a);

         }
         while((b=i2.read())!=-1)
         {
             o.write(b);
         }
        }

    }
}
```

now i am confused with how would i make the client side so that,the two users that are talking to each other,anyone could initiate the talking,and the message would receive at the other end,even if he is Writing something

i tried but wasn't successful this was the code

//

```
 class b {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("client started ,sendng connection request");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        Socket socket =new Socket("localhost",2001);
        System.out.println("connection completed .sending message");
        BufferedReader buf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintStream p=new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true)
        {
            String ack;
            if((ack=buf.readLine())!=null)
                System.out.println(ack);
            System.out.println("enter the message to send ,out to terminate");
            String msg=s.nextLine();
            p.println(msg);
            if(msg.equalsIgnoreCase("out"))
                break;

        }
        System.out.println("closing  connection");Thread.sleep(5000);
        socket.close();
        System.out.println("conection closed");
    }

}
```

can one one suggest what should i change so as i can achieve it.

Comment: You should consider editing your question title to better describe the problem, as it stands I suspect it won't attract many users

Comment: you should learn basic coding conventions, and try to write 'better' code, before starting in 'advanced' topics. naming conventions are there for a reason. allowing a main method to throw Exceptions is the same as hoping the application will crash while being used.
the main method should only be used as entry point of the application, not as the entire application.

Comment: @Stultuske it would have been better if you would have helped me,rather than this

Comment: Take a look at the Sockets tutorial at Oracle (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html). I think you'll find the "Writing a Client/Server Pair" example helpful.

Comment: user3380123 ... trust me, that is meant as help. 
you are trying to write a chat application, but you do it in way of coding that I would immediately toss away, if someone who had just learned about OO would show me that.
either that is not the code you are actual working on, or it's a complete disaster.
yes, I could 've pasted links to sockets and such, but when I talk to a builder, I wouldn't teach him how to build a roof, unless I'm convinced he's able to actually put a house underneath it first.

Comment: @Stultuske Any developer worth a damn would toss away his own code of 5 years ago. A server-client pair for chatting is not remotely advanced and is very often used as a pet project to teach or learn programming.